# Oracle SQL : comparing sum of rows data to one column

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have following type of data, where sum of interval_mins is supposed to be equal to Total_mins for a particular ID#. I need the rows where it is missing a row for Interval_mins e.g. for ID# 20. How can I do that? Thanks,

```
ID Date Interval_mins Total_mins
10 4/1/16  60              80
10 4/1/16  20              80
20 4/1/16  60              85
```

Comment: What do you want the results to be?

Comment: What do you expect to be returned?  Just a list of IDs?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the thrid row that is missing 25 mins in aggregation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for ids were the totals do not match:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having max(total_mins) <> sum(interval_mins);
```